# Why C++ Applications Can't Create Interfaces like php, html, and css?

Tags: php, html, c++, css, user-interface

I have a question that has always bugged me and wondered if someone could create some insight as to why programming languages like C++,python,C, Etc.. are still stuck essentially in the command line.  When I create for the web, I can utilize HTML, CSS , and PHP to both create the logic and interface quickly. So if I need a input box to show up at a specific location I write some css, and if I want that box to be populated with some data I can write some server side php.  With all the advances in today's software development why has interface design stayed in the stone age?  I understand there are things like Visual Studio for specific operating systems, but why is there not a Universal Set of Instructions that make interface design easier the way CSS design changed HTML?  I would find developing apps for the PC so much more fun if interface design was much easier.  Maybe there is and I have never come across it?

Comment: That's just not true, you can use python in webdev too.

Comment: Because C++ doesn't care about where it outputs to.  If you want a portable GUI for C++ check out Qt or wxWidgets

Comment: C++ wasn't designed with the web in mind because there really wasn't a web much to speak of. C was designed before there were even operating systems as you know them today. Python can make webapps very easily.

Comment: Because they are different languages? Why should all languages be similar? What would the point be, for different languages, if all languages would be similar?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Not the languages be the same, but a similar design framework.  So for example.  If I am creating a GUI Element, the design interface be universal. I am not wanting the languages to be web ready, I am talking more about why it is not easier to design interfaces for computer based applications the way CSS, and HTML can easily create an interface in a browser.

Comment: @DEVPROCB Your recent comment, reminded me of this [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/927/).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius haha, that is true.  Just bugs me the amount of time you have to spend on a GUI Interface for programming languages.  I feel like I should be able to just drop in an element program, quickly drop in the design elements on how I want it to display, and move on.  I guess it is true what they say, programmers are lazy.  I understand the languages need to be separated, but why hasn't someone come up with a solution for interface designers as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `c++`, GUI is separated from the language itself to provide more liberty to the developer. You can use any of the large variety of libs and frameworks for GUI.

Comment: When you say frameworks, is there a drop in framework for interface designers in c++ that will interpret a file the way a browser interprets css and html files?

Comment: @DEVPROCB I'm sure there's, unfortunately I don't know any.

Answer (score 2):

well frameworks like qt (c++) have made this easier by letting you easily create gui and be crossplatform  too. and html and css are just text that your browser interpret it and it does not deals with graphic hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Because thats not what c++ is intended to be that way, it's not the purpose of the language. C++ is a backend language, the more separated it is from the GUI, the better (Check out MVVM pattern for a good example).

But, if you want, you can always easily create a UI for any cpp program, there are plenty of good and easy-to-use libs/apis/tools for that.
Few platform independent examples that comes to mind: Qt (recommended only if the rest of your code is in Qt, otherwise it can be a pain), Gtkmm, libRocket, sciter, wxWidgets

Comment: I guess that is my point, as you stated, creating a gui can be a pain.  Is there no simple solution the way the browser can easily execute and interpret design elements in html.  So for example, if i need a checkbox in visual studio I can drag it onto the "Main Stage" but if I manipulate the size of the window that box will always stay in its stagnet position, unless you program further.  I guess I am looking for a way to create interfaces just as easily as I can in HTML and CSS.

Comment: Then just use a GUI library for that. there are plenty that's free for personal/opensource use.
The common ones are:
For html5: Qt, Wt
For native: Qt, Gtkmm
In MFC, you can change the behaviour of your stuff on preperties page, but I don't really like MFC to be honest, I think it's a little messy, and unpredictable. But, as always, it is possible that only I don't have enough experience with it, and that's why I prefer other solutions. :)